# Is WSO2 support de provisioning?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have gone through the WSO2 documentation and familiarize with provisioning concepts.But i did n't see any document related to  de-provisioning concept.So i am confusing that whether WSO2 Support de-provisioning  ,  Any suggestion ?If yes please suggest a reference doc. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server Support de-provisioning. When you execute delete operation, all provisioning connectors will be notified with delete request.

Comment: Got idea about it ,SCIM user deletion is a type of de-provisioning.